# Does any one know how to use IOCompletionPortTaskScheduler and IOTaskScheduler in ParallelExtensionExtras and what are their use?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Does any one know how to use the following classes in ParallelExtensionExtras and what they are used for?

```
IOCompletionPortTaskScheduler.cs
IOTaskScheduler.cs
```

Answer (score 4):

> **IOTaskScheduler**
>
> While we often refer to “the” .NET
> thread pool, the `ThreadPool`
> abstraction in .NET is actually built
> on top of two pools, one referred to
> as the worker pool and one referred to
> as the I/O pool.  The former is what’s
> targeted by the `QueueUserWorkItem`
> method as well as by the default
> `TaskScheduler`, while the latter is
> targeted by the
> `UnsafeQueueNativeOverlapped` method,
> and is frequently used for work in
> Windows Communication Foundation and
> Windows Workflow Foundation.  The
> `IOTaskScheduler` scheduler in the
> IOTaskScheduler.cs file runs tasks on
> this I/O thread pool via the
> `UnsafeQueueNativeOverlapped` method.

From here: [ParallelExtensionsExtras Tour – #7 – Additional TaskSchedulers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/)

Comment: It's mostly just there as another example of implementing a scheduler to target a particular execution environment.  There are actually two pools of threads in the one "ThreadPool", the worker pool and the I/O pool.  Typically, TPL targets the former (the same as QueueUserWorkItem).  There are other systems in .NET that target the latter, such as WCF.  So if you wanted to minimize oversubscription between WCF and TPL by having TPL tasks run in the same pool as WCF's work, you could use a scheduler something like the IOTaskScheduler.

Comment: From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e1e10df-d543-43af-9819-bb596e8d4aaa/iotaskscheduler-from-parallelextensionsextrastaskschedulers?forum=parallelextensions

Comment: This also gives some insight: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2008/11/24/threadpool-unsafequeuenativeoverlapped.aspx

Comment: Why will you want to use ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueNativeOverlapped instead of ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem? In our development, we discover an inefficiency of ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. If we have some alternate high and low number of work items, some of the threads may do busy waiting, artificially increase the CPU usage of our application. If you have the same pattern, and you have observed high CPU usage when it should not, you can try ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueNativeOverlapped. ***Me: This is an example of oversubscription

Answer (score 0):

> The **IOCompletionPortTaskScheduler** class offers a task scheduler that
>   uses an I/O completion port in order to control concurrency. It is
>   necessary to set the maximum number of threads in the scheduler to be
>   executing concurrently and the number of threads to have available in
>   the scheduler for executing tasks.

From here: http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/specialized-task-schedulers-in-net-4-par/228800428

And the following from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> **I/O completion ports** provide an efficient threading model for
>   processing multiple asynchronous I/O requests on a multiprocessor
>   system. When a process creates an I/O completion port, the system
>   creates an associated queue object for requests whose sole purpose is
>   to service these requests. Processes that handle many concurrent
>   asynchronous I/O requests can do so more quickly and efficiently by
>   using I/O completion ports in conjunction with a pre-allocated thread
>   pool than by creating threads at the time they receive an I/O request.